# What HTTP response code should be returned when a constraint fails?

Tags: api, rest, http, http-response-codes

We have two objects called `Track` and `Walkthru`. They are linked to each other through a `TrackWalkthruAssociation`. If a `Track` and `Walkthru` are associated with each other (i.e., a `TrackWalkthruAssociation` instance exists linking them together), neither one can be deleted unless the `TrackWalkthruAssociation` instance that links them together, is deleted **first**.

So sending a `DELETE` to `/tracks/1` or `/walkthrus/1` for example, when an association exists, should fail. What would the appropriate HTTP response code be, for this? I don't want to return a 500 because this is not an unexpected condition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Guess, it is OK to return: 409 ('Conflict').

The 409 error response tells the client that they tried to put the REST API’s resources
    into an impossible or inconsistent state.

In you case if you delete any of the linked resources before the link itself, you put resources into the `impossible` state.

More details & guidelines can be found in [RESTful Web APIs](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028468.do) or [REST API Design Rulebook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do)